# How to get new window height after resize in xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a UserControl that I've initialized with ResizeMode=CanResize but I need certain elements within the UserControl to depend on the window's height after the user resizes it by dragging the sides. Specifically, I need to the size of a TextBox to always have height that's 40 less than the window's height.

So how do I get this new window size after the user resizes?

Thanks!

NOTE:
Thanks to Pavel Anikhousk, using ActualHeight works. For future reference, this was my code:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ActualHeight, Converter={convs:ChatTextBoxSizeConverter}}" />
```

and ChatTextBoxSizeConverter.cs

```
namespace Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class ChatTextBoxSizeConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        private static ChatTextBoxSizeConverter instance_;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (System.Convert.ToInt32(value) - 40);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return instance_ ?? (instance_ = new ChatTextBoxSizeConverter());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your xaml code? Binding to `ActualHeight` seems to be an option

Comment: I did not know that ActualHeight worked like that. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how your layout is, but if you want to keep your window responsive and well designed this could be it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox />
</Grid>
```

Note the TextBox will fill the entire space, but a 40px is always reserved at the bottom.